# C Socket Part-1

Tags: c, socket, server, client

In my ongoing attempts to become a better blog writer I have some written some more code that needs reviewing.

Full Source: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/tree/master/Version1
First Article: https://lokiastari.com/posts/SocketProgramminginC

This is a Simple Client Server implementation using RAW Sockets.

### MakeFile

```
all:    client server
clean:
    rm -f *.o client server


CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror

client: client.o
server: server.o
```

### client.cpp

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE     1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: client <host> <Message>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize);

    write(socketId, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));

    shutdown(socketId, SHUT_WR);

    char    buffer[CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t  get = read(socketId, buffer, CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);

    buffer[get] = '\0';
    fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", "Response from server", buffer);

    close(socketId);
}
```

### server.cpp

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE      1024

int main()
{
    int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(socketId, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

    listen(socketId, 5);

    int                         finished    = 0;
    while(!finished)
    {
        struct  sockaddr_storage    serverStorage;
        socklen_t                   addr_size   = sizeof serverStorage;
        int newSocket = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverStorage, &addr_size);

        char        buffer[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int         get = read(newSocket, buffer, SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);

        buffer[get] = '\0';
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);

        write(newSocket, "OK", 2);

        fprintf(stdout, "Message Complete\n");

        close(newSocket);
    }
    close(socketId);
}
```

Comment: This server isn't capable of handling multiple connections. Are you aware of that? If that is one of the issues you'll be talking about I'd appreciate it if you show the non-blocking/event-oriented code using select (or some event library like libevent) along with the more common threaded approach. It's how fast servers are written these days - from node.js to lighthttpd to HAProxy. I generally consider the naive thread approach a mistake. You may want to talk about thread pools around event loops but that's a slightly more advanced topic.

Comment: @slebetman: Yes. I was going to mention select (and it being a bit old with some issues) but prefer to use `libevent`. But before I get there I want to implement a threaded version (then show the event driven version to show that it is better).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't resist saying this… the way you use a lot of whitespace to achieve your horizontal alignment, especially in `server.cpp`, is distracting and hinders readability.

I don't mind it so much when several lines have some relationship to each other.  For example:

> ```
> serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
> serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
> serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
> ```

But for this?  No, don't bother trying to horizontally align anything at all.

> ```
> struct  sockaddr_storage    serverStorage;
> socklen_t                   addr_size   = sizeof serverStorage;
> int newSocket = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverStorage, &addr_size);
>
> char        buffer[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
> int         get = read(newSocket, buffer, SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
> ```

Comment: I agree it does not work well there. Removing it.

Comment: @MartinYork Personalized spacing is a distraction.  Rather than comment on it much. I tend to copy the source code, press about 5 keys to auto-format it using a very standard style and then review.  If the reformatted code looks OK, all it well.  It not, the code is not well adapted to auto-formatting.  Save time.  Do **not** manually format code.  Auto-format it.

Answer (score 11):

One of the issues with TCP sockets is that there's no guarantee that sending N bytes in one go will result in receiving exactly N bytes after one call to `read()`. I would thus emphasize this by using a separator in the messages (newline perhaps?) and only printing out the result of what I've read after the whole line has been received.

I'd also try to get rid of magic numbers. `listen(socketId, 5);` makes me look at the manual to figure out what `5` is supposed to mean. A carefully named constant would make reading the code easier.

Comment: Yes I know about the read. That is a deliberate mistake so I can explicitly talk about it in my blog and show how to do it correctly.  http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/04/09/socket-read/

Comment: @MartinYork Good review etiquette: "deliberate mistake", for whatever reason, should be pointed out in the question or code.

Comment: Above Page movedd: http://localhost:3000/posts/SocketRead_Write

Answer (score 7):

Some issues that occur to me:

- The obvious problem is that there is no error checking.
- `memset` is often preferred to `bzero`, although I don't see why.  Also the
  cast of `serverAddr` to `char*` in the `bzero` call is unnecessary.
- port number should be shared in a header file
- is `inet_addr` the correct way to get the address?  Also note that it, too,
  can fail. And there is usually an `memcpy` involved in creating the address
  structure.
- does calling `shutdown` have any purpose?
- putting a 1k buffer on the stack would be a bad idea in some small systems
- the issue of `read` not returning all of what was written (or being
  interrupted) was already mentioned.  Also `read` returns `ssize_t` not
  `int` or `size_t`.
- finished variable is redundant.

Trivia

- Usage message might use argv[0] instead of assumed executable name.  Also
  the host must be a dotted address not a name.
- exit status might prefer EXIT_FAILURE
- I'd put "Response from server" in the format string.

Comment: The client calling `shutdown()` should tell the server that there is nothing more to read.

Comment: The `EXIT_FAILURE` macro is so ugly. But yes. @glampert also mentioned the `bzero()` issue in a review of the C++ version. Apparently its `archaic and non-standard` http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/131172/507 Apart from `shutdown` I will address all these issues. Thanks.

Comment: @LokiAstari, those are my words, hehe. But here is a more in-depth discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset (the archaic part is my own opinion, but the function is not part of the C or C++ standard).

Comment: Yes, I agree about `EXIT_FAILURE`, just being pedantic.  Also I forgot to note that the `finished` variable is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the naming of your files. The .c extension is for the C language and the .cpp extension is for the C++ language.  The tag on this question is [c](/questions/tagged/c), so the expectation is the file name extension would be .c, not .cpp.

Most compilers that can handle both languages look at the file name extension to determine which language to compile.

The posted code needs to check the returned values from: `socket()`, `bind()`, `read()`, `accept()`.

The variable `finished` is never updated, so it's not needed. Just use `while (1)`.