# Nisse Server: Part 2 Socket Layer

Tags: c++, c++14, socket

Getting close to a release of generic server.

[Nisse Server: Part 1 Helper Functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/168767/507)

Here is the socket layer code.
This has previously been reviewed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131137/c-socket-part-2). But there have been some changes.

#### Socket.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SOCKET_SOCKET_H
#define THORSANVIL_SOCKET_SOCKET_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

// An RAII base class for handling sockets.
// Socket is movable but not copyable.
class BaseSocket
{

    int     socketId;
    protected:
        static constexpr int invalidSocketId      = -1;

        // Designed to be a base class not used used directly.
        BaseSocket(int socketId, bool blocking = false);
    public:
        int getSocketId() const {return socketId;}
    public:
        virtual ~BaseSocket();

        // Moveable but not Copyable
        BaseSocket(BaseSocket&& move)               noexcept;
        BaseSocket& operator=(BaseSocket&& move)    noexcept;
        void swap(BaseSocket& other)                noexcept;
        BaseSocket(BaseSocket const&)               = delete;
        BaseSocket& operator=(BaseSocket const&)    = delete;

        // User can manually call close
        void close();
};

// A class that can read/write to a socket
class DataSocket: public BaseSocket
{
    public:
        DataSocket(int socketId, bool blocking = false)
            : BaseSocket(socketId, blocking)
        {}

        std::pair<bool, std::size_t> getMessageData(char* buffer, std::size_t size, std::size_t alreadyGot = 0);
        std::pair<bool, std::size_t> putMessageData(char const* buffer, std::size_t size, std::size_t alreadyPut = 0);
        void        putMessageClose();
};

// A class the conects to a remote machine
// Allows read/write accesses to the remote machine
class ConnectSocket: public DataSocket
{
    public:
        ConnectSocket(std::string const& host, int port, bool blocking = false);
};

// A server socket that listens on a port for a connection
class ServerSocket: public BaseSocket
{
    static constexpr int maxConnectionBacklog = 5;
    public:
        ServerSocket(int port, bool blocking = false);

        // An accepts waits for a connection and returns a socket
        // object that can be used by the client for communication
        DataSocket accept(bool blocking = false);
};

    }
}

#endif
```

#### Socket.cpp

```
#include "Socket.h"
#include "Utility.h"
#include "event.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Socket;
#pragma vera_pushoff
using SocketAddr    = struct sockaddr;
using SocketStorage = struct sockaddr_storage;
using SocketAddrIn  = struct sockaddr_in;
#pragma vera_pop

BaseSocket::BaseSocket(int socketId, bool blocking)
    : socketId(socketId)
{
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": bad socket: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }
    if (!blocking && evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(socketId) != 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": evutil_make_socket_nonblocking: failed to make non blocking: "));
    }
}

BaseSocket::~BaseSocket()
{
    if (socketId == invalidSocketId)
    {
        // This object has been closed or moved.
        // So we don't need to call close.
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        close();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // We should log this
        // TODO: LOGGING CODE HERE

        // If the user really want to catch close errors
        // they should call close() manually and handle
        // any generated exceptions. By using the
        // destructor they are indicating that failures is
        // an OK condition.
    }
}

void BaseSocket::close()
{
    return;
    if (socketId == invalidSocketId)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": accept called on a bad socket object (this object was moved)"));
    }
    while (true)
    {
        int state = ::close(socketId);
        if (state == invalidSocketId)
        {
            break;
        }
        switch (errno)
        {
            case EBADF: throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
            case EIO:   throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
            case EINTR:
            {
                        // TODO: Check for user interrupt flags.
                        //       Beyond the scope of this project
                        //       so continue normal operations.
                break;
            }
            default:    throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__, ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
        }
    }
    socketId = invalidSocketId;
}

void BaseSocket::swap(BaseSocket& other) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(socketId,   other.socketId);
}

BaseSocket::BaseSocket(BaseSocket&& move) noexcept
    : socketId(invalidSocketId)
{
    move.swap(*this);
}

BaseSocket& BaseSocket::operator=(BaseSocket&& move) noexcept
{
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

ConnectSocket::ConnectSocket(std::string const& host, int port, bool blocking)
    : DataSocket(::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), blocking)
{
    SocketAddrIn serverAddr{};
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(port);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(host.c_str());

    if (::connect(getSocketId(), reinterpret_cast<SocketAddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
    {
        close();
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::ConnectSocket::", __func__, ": connect: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }
}

ServerSocket::ServerSocket(int port, bool blocking)
    : BaseSocket(::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), blocking)
{
    SocketAddrIn    serverAddr = {};
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(port);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;

    if (::bind(getSocketId(), reinterpret_cast<SocketAddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
    {
        close();
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::ServerSocket::", __func__, ": bind: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }

    if (::listen(getSocketId(), maxConnectionBacklog) != 0)
    {
        close();
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::ServerSocket::", __func__, ": listen: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }
}

DataSocket ServerSocket::accept(bool blocking)
{
    if (getSocketId() == invalidSocketId)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::ServerSocket::", __func__, ": accept called on a bad socket object (this object was moved)"));
    }

    SocketStorage    serverStorage;
    socklen_t        addr_size   = sizeof serverStorage;
    int newSocket = ::accept(getSocketId(), reinterpret_cast<SocketAddr*>(&serverStorage), &addr_size);
    if (newSocket == -1)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::ServerSocket:", __func__, ": accept: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }
    return DataSocket(newSocket, blocking);
}

std::pair<bool, std::size_t> DataSocket::getMessageData(char* buffer, std::size_t size, std::size_t alreadyGot)
{
    if (getSocketId() == 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": accept called on a bad socket object (this object was moved)"));
    }

    std::size_t     dataRead  = alreadyGot;
    while (dataRead < size)
    {
        // The inner loop handles interactions with the socket.
        std::size_t get = ::read(getSocketId(), buffer + dataRead, size - dataRead);
        if (get == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1))
        {
            switch (errno)
            {
                case EBADF:
                case EFAULT:
                case EINVAL:
                case ENXIO:
                {
                    // Fatal error. Programming bug
                    throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": read: critical error: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
                case EIO:
                case ENOBUFS:
                case ENOMEM:
                {
                   // Resource acquisition failure or device error
                    throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": read: resource failure: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
                case EINTR:
                {
                    // TODO: Check for user interrupt flags.
                    //       Beyond the scope of this project
                    //       so continue normal operations.
                    continue;
                }
                case ETIMEDOUT:
                case EAGAIN:
                //case EWOULDBLOCK:
                {
                    // Temporary error.
                    // Simply retry the read.
                    return {true, dataRead};
                }
                case ECONNRESET:
                case ENOTCONN:
                {
                    // Connection broken.
                    // Return the data we have available and exit
                    // as if the connection was closed correctly.
                    return {false, dataRead};
                }
                default:
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": read: returned -1: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
            }
        }
        if (get == 0)
        {
            return {false, dataRead};
        }
        dataRead += get;
    }

    return {true, dataRead};
}

std::pair<bool, std::size_t> DataSocket::putMessageData(char const* buffer, std::size_t size, std::size_t alreadyPut)
{
    std::size_t     dataWritten = alreadyPut;

    while (dataWritten < size)
    {
        std::size_t put = ::write(getSocketId(), buffer + dataWritten, size - dataWritten);
        if (put == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1))
        {
            switch (errno)
            {
                case EINVAL:
                case EBADF:
                case ECONNRESET:
                case ENXIO:
                case EPIPE:
                {
                    // Fatal error. Programming bug
                    throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": write: critical error: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
                case EDQUOT:
                case EFBIG:
                case EIO:
                case ENETDOWN:
                case ENETUNREACH:
                case ENOSPC:
                {
                    // Resource acquisition failure or device error
                    throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": write: resource failure: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
                case EINTR:
                {
                    // TODO: Check for user interrupt flags.
                    //       Beyond the scope of this project
                    //       so continue normal operations.
                    continue;
                }
                case ETIMEDOUT:
                case EAGAIN:
                //case EWOULDBLOCK:
                {
                    // Temporary error.
                    // Simply retry the read.
                    return {true, dataWritten};
                }
                default:
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": write: returned -1: ", systemErrorMessage()));
                }
            }
        }
        dataWritten += put;
    }
    return {true, dataWritten};
}

void DataSocket::putMessageClose()
{
    if (::shutdown(getSocketId(), SHUT_WR) != 0)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::DataSocket::", __func__, ": shutdown: critical error: ", systemErrorMessage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `BaseSocket::close()` immediately returns. Is it intentional?

Comment: @vnp: no. You have found a bug.

Answer (score 2):

1. In-class-initialization of `socketId` to `invalidSocketId` would simplify things.
2. I would move much of the implementation of `BaseSocket` into the header as it's simple.
3. There's no reason not to have a `constexpr` `noexcept` default-ctor for `BaseSocket`.
4. Your use of libevent for abstracting the different handling of sockets on Windows and Unixoids is very intermittent. As an example, you use `evutil_make_socket_nonblocking()` but neither `evutil_closesocket()` nor `evutil_socket_t`.
5. Sometimes, you use your own custom constant `invalidSocketId`, sometimes `-1`. I couldn't find any use of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.
6. 166 is a bit long for a line. And there's no need, plenty of options for wrapping them to something sane. Remember that horizontal scrolling kills readability.
7. I would avoid spamming spaces trying to vertically align code-elements. Visually locking independent lines together makes changes cascade to non-modified lines, or leads to curious artifacts when not spreading them on every modification. There are such relics in your code...
8. Well, I don't think there's much to say about the `TODO` markers left.
9. `BaseSocket::close()` is very buggy:

   - As [vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp) remarked, [it starts with a spurious `return;`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168771/nisse-server-part-2-socket-layer#comment320612_168771), making it a no-op.
   - The `while(true)`-loop is useless.
   - On top of that, it returns zero on success, `-1` on failure.
10. I wonder why you make `maxConnectionBacklog` a constant instead of a (defaulted) ctor-argument for `ServerSocket`.
11. You know passing `nullptr` and `0` as the last two arguments to `::accept` is acceptable?
12. `DataSocket::getMessageData()` assumes `0` is an invalid socket handle. You *know* that's wrong.
13. There's no reason to proactively check whether the socket handle is valid. Just let the call to `read()` fail, as you did for `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

I added unit tests to my code above (after adding most of @Deduplicator suggestions. This discovered a few more issues:

The `close()` can fail leaving the object in an invalid state (Especially after fixing that spurious return).

```
void BaseSocket::close()
{
    // If you call close on a socket that is invalid then
    // there is a bug in the calling code (i.e. not my code).
    //
    // This means you have either previously closed the object
    // or have moved the socket to another object. Either is
    // a bad logic_error in the calling code.
    if (socketId == invalidSocketId)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__,
                                                 ": accept called on a bad socket object (this object was moved)"));
    }

    // Need a loop.
    // ::close may fail with EINTR which mean we  need to try again.
    while (true)
    {
        if (::close(socketId) == -1)
        {
            switch (errno)
            {
                // If we throw an exception this object is no longer
                // valid so set the state of the socket appropriately.
                // That way the destructor will not try close again.
                case EBADF: socketId = invalidSocketId;
                            throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__,
                                                                      ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
                case EIO:   socketId = invalidSocketId;
                            throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__,
                                                                       ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
                case EINTR:
                {
                    // TODO: Check for user interrupt flags.
                    //       Beyond the scope of this project
                    //       so continue normal operations.

                    // This was previously a break.
                    // It should be a continue.
                    continue;
                }
                default:    socketId = invalidSocketId;
                            throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("ThorsAnvil::Socket::BaseSocket::", __func__,
                                                                       ": close: ", socketId, " ", systemErrorMessage()));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    socketId = invalidSocketId;
}
```

Geting the hostaddress does not work as expected:

```
 serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(host.c_str());
```

The call `inet_addr()` converts a string in IP format into an address. But this is not really that useful. I needed a function that converts a hostname or IP address string into an address.

The `ConnectSocket` constructor allowed you to specific a non blocking connection (and it was the default). In reality that will not work for a connect call (as you are establishing the connection).

So I removed the option to making it nonblocking and it always passes true down to the base class.